# ReactJS rendering fields ín specific order in extended class

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple forms that share many rendered fields but not all. Therefore I have build a base form and want to extend it as necessary.

The issue is following: if my base component has field A, B, C and the extended component should have fields A,D,C .. how do I rendered that? How should my render look like according to best practice? Here is an example base form (the actual form is very big):

```
var BaseForm = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function() {
    return {data:FormStore.data};
  },
  defaultProps: function(){},

render: function () {
    return (
        <form id="form">
          <Field_A/>
          <Field_B/>
          <Field_C/>
        </form>
    )
}
})
```

I wonder how to arrange the render in an extended version of the BaseForm?

```
var Form = BaseForm.extend ({

render: function () {
    return (
         ???
    )
}
})
```

Comment: you want to rearrange the fields in base component, or want to put another filed in between of fields of base component ??

Comment: Actually, both. There will be version of the Form with some rearanged fields and other with add fields ..

Comment: @Stefan Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the examples where you can (and should) prefer `composition` over `inheritance`. Team react also [recommends](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) `composition` over `inheritance`.

In your case, You can create a generic stateless functional component to render all fields. You can pass the required attributes via `props`.

e.g.

```
const FormField= (props) => (
    <Field {...props} />
)
```

If you don't find above approach feasible for your case, then you can create separate stateless functional components for each of the field and use them wherever required.

```
const FieldA = (props) => (
    // FieldA specific functionality
    <Field />
)

const FieldB = (props) => (
    // FieldB specific functionality
    <Field />
)
```

and in the parent component use the above components.

```
render() {
    return (
        <form> 
           <FieldB />
           <FieldA />
        </form>
    );
}
```

**Edit**: As I mentioned in the comment, You can keep the mapping of all common Fields in your common component and any component that wishes to render all the fields will need to pass the array containing the sequence of the Fields. Now, You can iterate this sequence array and render all the fields in the sequence provided.

```
// common component
render() {
    let mapping = {
        'A': <FieldA />,
        'B': <FieldB />,
        'C': <FieldC />
    }
    return(
       <form>
          {this.props.fields.map((item, index) => {
              return <span key={index}>{mapping[item]}</span>;
          })}
       </form>
    );
}

// component that wish to render Fields in particular sequence.
<SuperForm fields={['B', 'A', 'C']} />
```

Here is the link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gktzx52j/).

Comment: This looks very much like what I already have, it remains quite ... verbose. The Form has currently around 50 fields and is to be expanded. I was hoping for something smaller really .. Thank you very much for you effort, I need to reconsider my approach to it.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for response. I've though of something like this, You can keep mapping of fields in the main component and any component that wish to render the form fields can pass the sequence of fields as an array. Now, You can iterate the array and render the specific Field matching the sequence. I'm not sure this is what you want, but I just thought of it and it might help you. I've created this small fiddle for you. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gktzx52j/). Can you take a look at it? Also, If you find any better approach then you can share.

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thanks a lot, that's exactly it. Awesome. If you update the answer with it, I will accept it.